# Formatting dates “day month year” with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, datetime

**What is the correct way to have “day month year” formatting in biblatex?**

Given this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{Book,
  title = {This is a Title},
  author = {Author, Some},
  location = {The City},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = 2005,
  month = feb,
  day = 14,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
Citing \cite{Book}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The bibliography reads:
[1] Some Author. This is a Title. The City: Publisher, February 14, 2005.

However, I would like:
[1] Some Author. This is a Title. The City: Publisher, 14 February 2005.

Can I do that without fiddling with `\printdate`?
The manual mentions that the date format is language-specific, yet I do want to continue in American English, just with a “day month year” style in the bibliography.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ah, a use for the `australian` language. Its date format is correct, so you can load it as a subsiduary language via `babel` and then wrap your bibliography in an `otherlanguage` environment:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[australian,american]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{Book,
  title = {This is a Title},
  author = {Author, Some},
  location = {The City},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = 2005,
  month = feb,
  day = 14,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\today

Citing \cite{Book}.

\begin{otherlanguage}{australian}
\printbibliography
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Creative solution :-)

Comment: I noted that reversing the order of `australian` and `english` messes up my hyphenation. Out of curiosity, could you explain why?

Comment: The last language that you specify is the one that becomes the default for the document.  In the babel definition files "australian" is a dialect of "british" and so uses "british" hyphenation rather than "american".  Avoid using the generic "english" it is not always obvious which variant it points to.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed a warning about `english` so I put `american` now. Seems a strange choice to have the _last_ one be the default, but it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually in the newer versions you can write `\usepackage[main=american,british]{babel}` explicitly specifying the main language.

Comment: So is the only difference between `british` and `australian` the date format? Then I'd change my document to `australian`, too, I guess because I'm not a particular fan of "20th September" in writing (but much less so of American mixed-endian).

Comment: @Christian Yes, (currently) the only difference in `babel`'s `english.ldf` between `british` and `australian` is the date format.  However, there may be documentclasses or style files out there that make other distinctions between the two.

Comment: It should be noted that **using the language `australian` changes much more than the date format** in comparison to `american` (alias `USenglish`). It also changes hyphenation rules, serial comma use, type of quotation marks used, and the relative positions of quotation marks and end-punctuation.

Answer (score 15):

As the manual says :

> The biblatex package always treats [english] as an alias for american. It is 
>   preferable to use the language identifiers american and british

you can use something like :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{Book,
title = {This is a Title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = 2005,
month = feb,
day = 14,
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\today
Citing \cite{Book}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=other,backend=biber,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{Book,
  title = {This is a Title},
  author = {Author, Some},
  location = {The City},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  hyphenation = {british}
  date = 2005,
  month = feb,
  day = 14,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\today
Citing \cite{Book}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You *can* use `australian`, but that also affects hyphenation, comma, and quotation rules in comparison to `american` (alias `USenglish`). If you just want to make the day come before the month (in both long and short dates), you should just change the way the dates are printed in the `american`/`USenglish` language. Note that this will change the date format of the entire document, rather than just the bibliography.

The simplest way is to insert this in the preamble:

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{USenglish}{%

  % d-m-y format for long dates
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%

  % d-m-y format for short dates
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
```

I wrote the code with the alias `USenglish`, but you can replace that with `american` if you choose. They are two names for the same style. You need to be sure that it's the same alias used when calling `\usepackage{babel}`, though. (If you change the properties of `USenglish`, don't expect the changes to be carried over to `american`!)

A more elegant solution is to make an .lbx file to stay more organized and make this style easily accessible in future documents. The code only differs at the beginning and end. You need to add `\ProvidesFile` to the top and `\endinput` to the bottom. Then add two `\Inherit...` commands and change any `\Define...` commands to `Declare...` commands.

```
\ProvidesFile{USenglish-dmy.lbx}[USenglish localization with d-m-y format for dates]

\InheritBibliographyExtras{USenglish}
\DeclareBibliographyExtras{%

  % d-m-y format for long dates
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%

  % d-m-y format for short dates
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}

\InheritBibliographyStrings{USenglish}
\endinput
```

Save this as `USenglish-dmy.lbx` and then add this in your preamble: `\DeclareLanguageMapping{USenglish}{USenglish-dmy}`. That's it! Now all dates should have the day before the month, and nothing else (e.g. hyphenation or quotation styles) is affected.

Thanks to moewe for [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141412/46459) that helped me arrive at this solution.

Answer (score 7):

One very simple way to change biblatex's date format so the day comes before the month is to add the option `language=australian` when loading biblatex. This has the following features:

- Only affects the bibliography.
- Doesn't require babel or polyglossia.
- Doesn't require the use of any language commands when calling `\printbibliography`.
- Explicitly choosing the language prevents biblatex from "guessing" incorrectly.

Call the option like this (see line 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,dateabbrev=false,language=australian]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{Book,
title = {This is a Title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005-02-14},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\today

Citing \cite{Book}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output example showing dd Month YYYY in bibliography but Month dd, YYYY for "\today"]

---

You could use `UKenglish` (alias `british`) instead of `australian`; you will then get "14th" instead of "14". **Please note, however, that using either `british` or `australian` will also change the style of hyphenation, serial commas, and quotation marks in comparison to `USenglish` (alias `USenglish`).**

The `language` option is explained in section 3.1.2.1 of the [biblatex documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (ver. 2.8a):

> This option controls multilingual support. When set to autobib, autocite or auto,
>   biblatex will try to get the main document language from the babel/polyglossia
>   package (and fall back to English if babel/polyglossia is not available). It is also
>   possible to select the document language manually.

Comment: While your MWE certainly works, using `polyglossia` is not only not required but it seems to overrule the `language=` setting

Answer (score 2):

*For user of `polyglossia` the relevant information is available elsewhere on this site but I had difficulties finding it, so I add this here to link to the relevant answers:*

Due to a [bug in polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324849/how-do-we-get-polyglossia-language-variants-to-work-with-biblatex-bibliographies) it is not possible to set language-variants in a way that is available to e.g. `biblatex`. Thus `\selectlanguage[variant=australian,ordinalmonthday=false]{english}` will make `\today` produce "24 May 2018" but `\printbibliography` will still render US-style dates ("May 24, 2018").

[But it is now possible with](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413592/6819) `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{australian}` to make `biblatex` use the right format.

Comment: Currently: Try to avoid `polyglossia` if at all possible. If you are mainly writing in Latin script (and surely for (western) European languages) there is little need for `polyglossia`'s extra features and `babel` works just fine. Even for some more complicated script systems `babel` is making progress. `polyglossia` on the other hand has not gotten a proper bug-fix release in ages (the April 2018 release was more of a maintenance release and did not address many open bug reports), see https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues