# DMY date and serial comma with Biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I am quite new to LaTeX, but I've been piecing some things together to develop a template with the style I use. Specifically, I need to use the Annals of the Association of American Geographers (AAG) style, which is a modified Chicago style. I have managed to almost get what I need for citations (which has been no small feat); I can currently generate the following:

[image: a sample of my bibliogrphic style]

However, to be compliant with the AAG style I need to have the date in the format dd Mon. yyyy. In searching around, I've found the suggestion to use Australian English via babel, which gives me this:

[image]

Unfortunately, now the serial comma has been dropped from the authors list.

Here is the MWE of my TeX (with Australian):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[australian,american]{babel}

\usepackage[authordate-trad, backend=biber, dateabbrev=true, firstinits=true, maxcitenames=3, isbn=false, doi=false, eprint=false]{biblatex-chicago}

%Set custom strings for url and date labels (available at and last accessed)
\NewBibliographyString{available}
\NewBibliographyString{urlwhen}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  available = {Available at},
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlwhen = {last accessed},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{available}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlwhen}\addcolon\space{#1}}}

% Set url + date appearance in bib (add doi here if needed)
\renewbibmacro*{bib+doi+url}{%
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}
  }

%Remove Quotes around titles
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{biblio.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{article}

\renewcommand*{\bibname}{References}
\begin{otherlanguage}{australian}
\printbibliography 
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

And here is the .bib:

```
@article{article,
 Author = {Brown, J. C. and Jepson, W. E. and Kastens, J. H. and Wardlow, B. D. and Lomas, J. M. and Price, K. P.},
 Number = {2},
 Pages = {117-148},
 Title = {Multitemporal, moderate-spatial-resolution remote sensing of modern agricultural production and land modification in the Brazilian Amazon},
 Url = {http://www.somehost.org/somefolder/somefile.pdf},
 Urldate = {2013-10-27},
 Volume = {44},
 Year = {2007}}
```

Does anyone have an thoughts as to the best way to get what I need? That is, how can I get the date format without losing the comma?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also a way without switching the language to `australian`, which in my opinion is not the best idea if your document is actually `american`.

You will just have to tell `biblatex` to change the date format for `american` by putting the following chunk of code into your preamble.

You can find the definitions in `australia.lbx`, the other date formats are inherited from `british.lbx`. Just copy the relevant definitions from there (relevant are `\mkbibdatelong`, `\mkbibdateshort`, if it is used also `\mkbibordinal`).

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
```

If you plan on using this date format more often, an even more `biblatex`-y way would be to create a new localisation file named `american-dmy.lbx` with the following content

```
\ProvidesFile{american-dmy.lbx}[american localisation with dmydate format for long dates]

\InheritBibliographyExtras{american}
\DeclareBibliographyExtras{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
\InheritBibliographyStrings{american}
\endinput
```

And load this language configuration via

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-dmy}
```

A fully self-contained MWE for the second solution (if you use it in your document you will have the `.bib` file and `american-dmy.lbx` somewhere LaTeX can find it and can omit the `filecontents`, of course)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[authordate-trad, backend=biber, dateabbrev=true, firstinits=true, maxcitenames=3, isbn=false, doi=false, eprint=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-dmy}

\begin{filecontents}{american-dmy.lbx}
\ProvidesFile{american-dmy.lbx}[american localisation with dmydate format for long dates]

\InheritBibliographyExtras{american}
\DeclareBibliographyExtras{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
\InheritBibliographyStrings{american}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article,
 Author = {Brown, J. C. and Jepson, W. E. and Kastens, J. H. and Wardlow, B. D. and Lomas, J. M. and Price, K. P.},
 Number = {2},
 Pages = {117-148},
 Title = {Multitemporal, moderate-spatial-resolution remote sensing of modern agricultural production and land modification in the Brazilian Amazon},
 Url = {http://www.somehost.org/somefolder/somefile.pdf},
 Urldate = {2013-10-27},
 Volume = {44},
 Year = {2007}}
\end{filecontents}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
  url = {available at},
  urlseen = {last accessed},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space{#1}}}

% Set url + date appearance in bib (add doi here if needed)
\renewbibmacro*{bib+doi+url}{%
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
}

%Remove Quotes around titles
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{article}

\renewcommand*{\bibname}{References}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

---

Note also that it is better to use capitalisation as if the word were to appear mid-sentence than at the beginning ("Note that all expressions should be capitalized as they usually are when used in the middle of a sentence. The `biblatex` package will automatically capitalize the first word when required at the beginning of a sentence. Expressions intended for use in headings should be capitalized in a way that is suitable for titling" [`biblatex` documentation v. 2.8](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), §3.8 "Localization Commands", p. 90. I changed `available = {Available at},` to `available = {available at},`.). Also `biblatex` already provides localisation strings for the URL (called `url`) and `urlseen` for the date the URL was visited, so you could use those instead of declaring new ones.

Comment: Thanks for your very comprehensive answer. I agree, using `australian` is not ideal as I am writing in `american`. This is a much better way to do this, and I learned a lot from you post.

Comment: @phoetrymaster Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 3):

In further digging into the docs and experimenting with this, I managed to find a way to do it. Adding the following to the document will add in the serial comma and keep the Australian date format:

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{australian}{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{\addcomma\addspace}
}
```

The result being:

[image: Success! Proper reference format]