# How do we get Polyglossia language variants to work with Biblatex bibliographies?

Tags: biblatex, xetex, languages, polyglossia

### Intro

I'm testing development versions of the `biblatex` package (3.5) with the `biber` (Date modified 2016-08-03 18:31) backend. These versions add various kinds of date support (e.g. approximate dates, BCE/BC dates, datetimes).

I'm trying to get `biblatex` to work with `polyglossia` (Version 1.42.1; packaged on 2016-03-29). Specifically for the dates in bibliographic entries to be affected by the `polyglossia` language `variant` setting. Chiefly - for the day, month, and year sequence; and month names - to be language dependent.

I'm using the xetex engine.

My minimal working example (MWE) is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{barker_2016_swiss,
    author = {Barker, Anne},
    title = {Swiss voters say no to guaranteed free money},
    date = {2016-06-06},
    journaltitle = {ABC News},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{fontspec}

%\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear,%
  alldates=long,%
  language=auto,%
  autolang=langname,%
  backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Current language: \currentlang. \autocite{barker_2016_swiss}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### Result

I get:

> Current language: english. (Barker 2016)
>   **References**
>   Barker, Anne (June 6, 2016). “Swiss voters say no to guaranteed free money”.
>   In: ABC News.

That is, the output seems to format the date as american english (which is the default in biblatex for later versions).

### Expected

I expected, however, "Current language: british" and the date to be formatted as "6th June 2016". And indeed I get that if I change my MWE to use `babel` ...

```
\usepackage[british]{babel}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
```

... that is, the result is (as I would expect) ...

> Current language: british. (Barker 2016)
>   **References**
>   Barker, Anne (6th June 2016). “Swiss voters say no to guaranteed free money”.
>   In: ABC News.

### Testing polyglossia with main language

Also if I use `polyglossia` with a main language setting, rather than a variant, then I get expected results. I.e. If in my MWE I have

```
%\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
```

... then I get ...

> Current language : french. (Barker 2016)
>   **Références**
>   Barker, Anne (6 juin 2016). “Swiss voters say no to guaranteed free money”.
>   In : ABC News.

### Problem summary

In summary, with my MWE, `babel` and `polyglossia` work as expected with `biblatex` when using `\usepackage[*mainlanguage*]{babel}` and `\setdefaultlanguage{*mainlanguage*}` respectively. But `polyglossia` doesn't work when using `\setdefaultlanguage[variant=*somevariantlanguage*]{english}`.

### Other considerations

I've ran this past the biblatex developer (of date support), @PLK, and [they wrote](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/427#issuecomment-239684707)

> I think there are some issues with Polyglossia still - there has been a release pending for some time to fix some of these issues I think.

I've tried using the LuaTex engine, with no joy.

Setting `\usepackage[ ... language=british ....]{biblatex}` doesn't help.

At this point it feels like a bug in Polyglossia. But before raising an issue at the Polyglossia github I'd appreciate if anyone can identify anything wrong that I'm doing. Also if anyone can reproduce this issue with a production version of `biblatex/biber` that'd save me the rigmarole of downgrading.

### Updates:

2016-08-16 07:39: From the comments this appears to be a Polylossia issue. And so I've posted [Github > Polyglossia > Exposing Polyglossia language variants to other packages like Biblatex. #154](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/154). (Edit: 2016-08-16 08:00 corrected link)

2016-08-17 19:31 My workaround will be to use `babel` (with thanks to @UlrikeFischer for clearing the way to it).

Comment: I see the problem in a current biblatex too. I'm not sure if I would call it a bug in polyglossia, it is more missing (a lot) code. Polyglossias gloss-english.ldf changes \today for british but beside this it doesn't seem to do anything to adapt date formats or to offer a sensible interface for packages like biblatex. Why are you using it instead of the (working) babel?

Comment: Indeed, it "just" seems to be the problem that language variant detection with `polyglossia` does not really work in `biblatex`. (The `csquotes` package, which was devised by the same author as `biblatex`, has a footnote: "Note that `polyglossia` support is currently in a preliminary state because `polyglossia` is lacking a
proper interface for other packages. In practice, this means that `csquotes` can detect the language (e.g., `english`) but not the language variant (e.g., `british`).")

Comment: I think I submitted a patch for polyglossia to make it report the variant but I don't think it ever made it into a new release. It was a while ago.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've updated the post to link to a github polyglossia issue I've created.  Thanks for the test. I'm using polyglossia over the working babel only because polyglossia is made out, both in the babel and polyglossia documentation, to supercede babel for the Xetex and LuaTex engines (and I like the unicode support of either engine). I'm open to have that understanding challenged. In any case it looks like I will have to use babel until the polyglossia variant language issue is addressed.

Comment: @moewe I've updated the post to link to a github polyglossia issue I've created. Thanks for quoting the csquotes documentation. That shed light on the state of play.

Comment: @plk thanks. I've updated the post to link to a github polyglossia issue I've created. From there I link to what might be the patch you are recalling.

Comment: The core of babel is nowadays  "luatex and xelatex ready."  There are imho still a number of language files which won't work and some languages are missing. But english (and french and german) works fine and here I would currently prefer babel over polyglossia -- also as bugs are corrected faster in babel.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks. That prompted me to do some general testing with babel (being new to it) under Xetex. And indeed it seems to give me everything I want (with other packages apart from `biblatex`, like `datetime2` and `csquotes`).  One can even create `polyglossia` compatible language wrappers like `\begin{german} ... \end{german}` (in the doc body), by using `\babeltags{german=german}` in the preamble. All that makes the current "workaround", of using `babel`, so far painless.

Comment: @PLK I’m sorry to say that your pull request didn’t work and introduced new bugs which I tried to correct as you can see on https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/pull/122 and I still can’t guarantee it is working correctly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I certainly agree with your assessment.

Answer (score 4):

> **Update** All multilingual features of `biblatex` should work as intended with `biblatex` v3.14 (or above) and `polyglossia` v1.46 (or above).
>
> The MWE gives the expected (`babel`-equivalent) output now.
>
> If you are facing any problems with `polyglossia` and `biblatex`, update your system so that you have at least `biblatex` 3.14 (and a matching Biber version) and `polyglossia` 1.46.
>   If that does not help, please open a bug report at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues.
>
> The rest of this answer below is kept for historic interest.

Just so this gets an answer.

The [documentation of `csquotes`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf), which was devised by the same author as `biblatex` and uses similar techniques, states on p. 2

> Note that `polyglossia` support is currently in a preliminary state because `polyglossia` is lacking a proper interface for other packages. In practice, this means that `csquotes` can detect the language (e.g., `english`) but not the language variant (e.g., `british`).

The same considerations hold for `biblatex`. Since `polyglossia` does not offer an interface to detect the language variant used, `biblatex` always uses only the main language. In your example that means that no matter which `variant` you selected, only `english.lbx` is loaded, so you can not get `british.lbx` with `polyglossia`.

A viable work-around for some languages is to switch to `babel` instead of `polyglossia`. For `british` this is certainly an option. But it might not be that easy for other languages.

Starting from `biblatex` 3.11 you can use `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{british}` as a workaround. This is *not* the intended use of `\DeclareLanguageMapping`, but works currently **as a workaround** as long as you don't use `english` in your document. (There is no guarantee this will continue to work as misusing the language mapping for different dialects or languages instead of stylistic versions is explicitly discouraged in the documentation.)

---

I have covered the difficulties with `polyglossia` in my answer to [\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix, inheritance, and polyglossia in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432347/35864) from a more technical side. I won't repeat the entire explanation, but in short the problem arises as follows.

`babel` treats language dialects/variants basically as languages in their own right with an `.ldf` file and a separate identifier. `polyglossia` on the other hand has the concept of a main language that can be modified with attributes/options. One of the most prominent options is the `variant`, which as it so happens corresponds for English pretty much to the `babel` dialects. For German `variant` and `spelling` are needed. There is neither a binding convention as to what attributes should be used for language variants, nor is there a uniform implementation of the attributes across language modules. This makes it extremely hard for packages to detect the language variant used by `polglossia` and translate it into a `babel` language name (or vice versa).

Comment: As a supplementary note, I wrote an article in TUGBoat about the problem of packages trying to determine the document's localisation settings. [Localisation of TeX documents: tracklang. 37:3, 2016](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-3/tb117talbot.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating, as the easiest solution, a Polyglossia `gloss-australian.ldf` file (see [SE question 166739](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166739/main-text-and-bibliography-in-two-languages-but-with-alternate-date-format/481511#481511)), which is just `gloss-english.ldf` with a few minor tweaks, so that the language `australian` would flow into Biblatex and the dates come out in Australian format.

Decoupling the administrative processing (what is `the` default setting for a language/dialect cluster?) from the operational processing (what are the specific settings for each `variant`/`dialect`?) could be the way to go, for easier maintenance and usage, and so on.

Similar, as I see it, topologically speaking, to how the Strafgesetzbuch is organized into a General part and a Special or Specific part, compared with how higgledy-piggledy the statutes are here in Australia. Keeping the relationship between objects separate from the objects themselves, is another way of phrasing it.

There's not enough code in `gloss-english.ldf` at the moment to deal with processing half a dozen sets of (really independent) settings (`variants`), and setting up the default processing as well, all in, in effect, one `if` statement. Valiant attempt, though. And a good start.

Next step on the Australian side is being able to do all three date formats in the same document/bibliography, and further,  keeping original formatting when quoting/citing from other jurisdictions and/or styles.