# biblatex uses American date format with british polyglossia

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia

While checking my references I noticed that the `urldate` is printed in the wrong format. My document is being typeset in British English, where it is common to write the date as `Day/Month/Year`, compared to the American format `Month/Day/Year`. The output of my references, however, is in the American format.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant = british]{english}

\usepackage[backend = biber, citestyle = numeric-comp, language = british]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @misc{Test,
        author = {NanoTemper},
        title = {{This is a test title}},
        year = {2019},
        url = {https://example.com},
        urldate = {2019-05-21}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
    Foo bar\cite{Test}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

What should I use to get the British date format?

Comment: Is using `babel` instead of `polyglossia` an option? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464281/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324849/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432347/35864 (Cf. also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482396/35864)

Comment: Well, I can try if it works, but as I'm using (and also have to) `XeLaTeX` it could be complicated. Wasn't `polyglossia` developed as a potential replacement for `babel`when using `XeLaTeX`?

Comment: BTW: The next version of `biblatex` will warn about `polyglossia` to avoid these things slipping past. https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/845

Comment: Yes, but `polyglossia` development has effectively stalled in recent years. For languages with Latin script `polyglossia` offers very little to no advantage at all (it might even be worse for some languages, apparently French would be such a case). If you have non-Latin (especially RTL) scripts, things might be different.

Comment: Okay, thanks! The document looks fine so I guess that `babel` works fine in my case. And well, the date is in the correct output.