# Localized date with biblatex and polyglossia

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia

I cannot get localized dates in the bibliography when using polyglossia and biblatex.
Biblatex's manual says:

> biblatex automatically adjusts to the main document language if babel or polyglossia is loaded

However, the following document does not produce the desired output.

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@Article{reference,
  author        = {Doe, John},
  title         = {Some title},
  journaltitle  = {Awesome Journal},
  volume        = {12},
  number        = {8},
  pages         = {1234-5678},
  date          = {2018-12-11},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\usepackage[language=auto]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}

\begin{document}
Citation~\cite{reference}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The reference is typeset as

> John Doe. “Some title”. In: Awesome Journal 12.8 (Dec. 11, 2018), pp. 1234–5678.

While I want the date as

> 11 Dec. 2018

What am I missing?

Comment: Language variant detection with `polyglossia` is complicated and does not quite work in `biblatex` (see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432347/35864), if you don't have a very good reason to use `polyglossia` I would strongly urge you to use `babel` where everything works as expected. (While `polyglossia` was intended to be a replacement for `babel` in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX in recent years development has stalled and bug reports are mounting https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues - to be fair not all open issues will be bugs, while `babel` is again actively developed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [How do we get Polyglossia language variants to work with Biblatex bibliographies?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324849/35864), `biblatex`'s `polyglossia` interface has always been a bit shaky, in particular the detection of language variants does not work. The technical reasons for that are outlined in [\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix, inheritance, and polyglossia in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432347/35864). With `babel` language dialects work as expected.

If there is no good reason why you would need `polyglossia`, I strongly recommend you use `babel` instead. While `polyglossia` was intended as a replacement for `babel` for LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX and has been recommended over `babel` for those engines in the past, I believe that the current state of the development of the packages, namely that `babel` is actively being developed and new features for non-European scripts are added whereas `polyglossia` development has been relatively slow in the past years, has made that advice obsolete. There are a few areas where `polyglossia` still has an edge on `babel`, especially with respect to non-European scripts, but that edge is slowly getting smaller. If you are only planning to write in Western European languages, there is absolutely no reason to prefer `polyglossia` over `babel`, see for example [this recent comment on the `texhax` mailing list](https://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2018-December/023420.html). See also [Decide between Polyglossia and Babel for LuaLaTeX in 2019](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482396/35864), [Decide between Polyglossia and Babel for XeLaTeX in 2019](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482611/35864).

If you *must* use `polyglossia` there is a workaround, which is explicitly **not recommended**. You can remap the `english` localisation to `british` with

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{british}
```

To quote the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), p. 303

> Note that `\DeclareLanguageMapping` is not intended to handle language
>   variants (e.g., American English vs. British English) or `babel`/`polyglossia`
>   language aliases (e.g., `USenglish` vs. `american`).

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/845

Comment: I found in many places that polyglossia was supposed to be a modern replacement of babel, which would not work at all with LuaLaTeX. I suppose that was outdated advice. Babel seems to work fine. I mostly write in English and other European (Latin) languages, I guess polyglossia does not bring any particular advantage to me.