# Decide between Polyglossia and Babel for XeLaTeX in 2019

Tags: xetex, babel, polyglossia, incompatibility

Which are the key questions one has to ask to **decide between Polyglossia and Babel for a XeLaTeX project in 2019**?

There has been a similar, more general [question in 2012](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88481/polyglossia-vs-babel), but the packages have changed a lot in the meantime. Hence I open a new, more specific question.

For LuaLaTeX see: [Decide between Polyglossia and Babel for LuaLaTeX in 2019](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482396/decide-between-polyglossia-and-babel-for-lualatex-in-2019)

Comment: I’m not sure whether to edit this to say 2020. Do people reading this want a comparison of the versions in TeX Live 2019, specifcially?

Comment: Obviously is better  without  "2019", but not to add "2020", nor "TeX Live". Just "at the present", without expiration dates and without a specific distro.

Comment: @Fran no, because this does not fit into the SX system. The authors will not update their answer continuously and the "right answer" might change too.

Comment: @JonasStein That the "right answer" might change is precisely a very good reason to update answers or add new answers to old questions and this site encourages this (everybody can edit, revival badges, etc.), but in any case will not occur "continuously" . With the precedents, luckily every five years or so.... On the other hand, If both packages are in several TeX distros supported by several OS, I do not see why should be relevant to limit the scope of the question to one distro version because whatever does not fit in some system.