# Change biblatex short date format

Tags: biblatex, date, locale

I'm writing my document in British English, but live in the Netherlands. In the Netherlands, the short date format is dd-mm-yyyy, as opposed to the British dd/mm/yyyy.

How can I get biblatex to use this date format for its short dates?

I can't use the solution in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166740/99413) to a related question, as that would also change the localisation of the bibliography, and frankly, the other answers to that answer are pretty much Greek to me. Surely there must be an easier way?

I've tried adding `\usepackage[dutch]{datetime2}`, `\DTMsetdatestyle{dutch}`, but that has no effect whatsoever.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
    author = {A. Author},
    title = {Some title},
    url = {example.org},
    urldate = {2019-12-31}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{key}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Using `\usepackage[dutch]{babel}` is able to give the right date format, so it *should* be possible.

Current output is

```
A. Author, “Some title”, [Online]. Available: example.org (visited on 31/12/2019).
```

Desired output:

```
A. Author, “Some title”, [Online]. Available: example.org (visited on 31-12-2019).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the date formatting macros `\mkbibdatelong` and `\mkbibdateshort` from the Dutch language module `dutch.lbx` and use them in `\DefineBibliographyExtras`. This probably qualifies as looking a bit Greek, since it essentially does the same as [the accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166982/35864) to [Main text and bibliography in two languages but with alternate date format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166739/35864) (except the linked answer uses a new `.lbx` file, whereas we just write the code into the preamble with a slightly different command), but I feel that this is the intended way to do things. While `biblatex` lets you easily choose between different formats for the same language with options (`urldate=long`/`urldate=short` for example), it is a bit more involved if you want to use a format not supported by the language files because that involves redefining one or more of the macros responsible for printing the dates.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\mbox{-}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\mbox{-}}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
    author = {A. Author},
    title = {Some title},
    url = {example.org},
    urldate = {2019-12-31}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{key}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: visited on 31-12-2019]

Comment: Thanks, this works.
For future readers, note that the first part (`\def\mkbibdatelong`...) also changes the long format from ordinal numbers to normal numbers, i.e. 1st Jan. 2000 becomes 1 Jan. 2000. In my case, I like this.