# dd.mm.yyyy date formatting in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, formatting, date

So this might be a bit specific of a question, but I need BibLaTeX to output dates in the long DMY format - dd.mm.yyyy that is.

BibLaTeX documentation states that one can achieve dd/mm/yyyy by using the `date = terse` setting.

However, I'd like to have the date separator to be a dot instead of a slash. I didn't find any easy way to do this while browsing through the documentation.

Here's an MWE (and its output) on what I'm working on, roughly. I have been modifying the `style = chem-rsc` package to fit my needs (or rather my Uni's requirements), but I've omitted those changes here for they are irrevelent in this case.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,british]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style     = chem-rsc,
    autocite  = superscript,
    autopunct = true,
    sorting   = none,
    sortcites = true,
    eventdate = terse,
    datezeros = true,]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{viitteet.bib}
@inproceedings{othusitse2015,
    author      = {Nhlanhla Othusitse and Edison Muzenda},
    title       = {Predictive Models of Leaching Processes: A Critical Review},
    booktitle   = {7th Int. Conf. on Latest Trends in Engineering \& Technology},
    location    = {Irene, Pretoria, South Africa},
    eventdate   = {2015-11-26/2015-11-27},
    pages       = {136--141},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{viitteet.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\supercite{othusitse2015}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT:

I tried tinkering with something like this...

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
    \renewrobustcmd*{\bibdatesep}{\adperiod}
}
```

... but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome! Does it work with the default styles? That is, if you just have `\usepackage{biblatex}` without changing the defaults, do you get the right separator in that case? Obviously not a solution, but it will tell you if the problem is in the `\DefineBibliographyExtras` or something the style/options are doing. If it works with the default, experiment to isolate the option causing the issue. (Probably the style, but worth checking.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the default formatting for British English turns out as
(26th-27th Nov. 2015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [moewes answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485027/29873), you can copy the date formatting macros from a language definition file, that has the desired date format, i.e. `german.lbx`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,british]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style     = chem-rsc,
    autocite  = superscript,
    autopunct = true,
    sorting   = none,
    sortcites = true,
    eventdate = terse,
    datezeros = true,]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
\protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}\adddot
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\thinspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}
         {}
         {\iffieldundef{#3}{/}{\adddot\thinspace}}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{viitteet.bib}
@inproceedings{othusitse2015,
    author      = {Nhlanhla Othusitse and Edison Muzenda},
    title       = {Predictive Models of Leaching Processes: A Critical Review},
    booktitle   = {7th Int. Conf. on Latest Trends in Engineering \& Technology},
    location    = {Irene, Pretoria, South Africa},
    eventdate   = {2015-11-26/2015-11-27},
    pages       = {136--141},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{viitteet.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\supercite{othusitse2015}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Many thanks, DG'!