# biblatex show urldate as full date

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to use `biblatex` to format the reference to print the urldate in long form (Australian order) to match my university's style guide.  I modified all the other fields using `biblatex.cfg`

I want the visited date to print the full date

> Soto, S. 2013, Ubuntu documentation Install CD Customization, ed. by
>   Community Help Wiki last edited 27 February 2013, visited on 25
>   September 2015, url:
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization.

My `biblatex.cfg` is

```
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
   \addperiod\space\printfield{labelyear}%
   \printfield{extrayear}}}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space{#1}\addcomma}
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
\iffieldundef{urlyear}
  {}
  {\setunit*{\addspace}%
   \usebibmacro{urldate}}
\usebibmacro{url}}
\endinput
```

In my MWE files I have the following fields set

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, natbib=true, backend=biber, dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@Online{ubuntu-preseed-dvd,
Title                    = {Ubuntu documentation Install CD Customization},
Author                   = {Soto, S.},
Date                     = {2013-02-27},
Editor                   = {Community Help Wiki last edited 27 February 2013},
Url                      = {https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization},
Urldate                  = {2015-09-25}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{ubuntu-preseed-dvd}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Where the date is printed as 09/25/2015.

How can I get `biblatex` to print as 25 September 2015?

Comment: Try the option `urldate=long`. (Plus minus the well known "American date formatting puts the month first problem", which can be solved by not the British language, or Australian, see [Formatting dates “day month year” with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129170/35864))

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 10):

Simply use `urldate=long` to get the expanded date format for URL dates, the default is the more compressed `short` you see at the moment.

If you want the months spelled out, you need `dateabbrev=false` as well (as commented by [Florian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6819/florian)), that option is independent of the generic `abbreviate` option that controls whether bibstrings are printed in full/long or short form.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, urldate=long, dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
  url     = {https://example.com/gov/sir-humphrey/importance-civil-service},
  urldate = {2018-08-23},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Appleby, Humphrey (1980). *On the Importance of the Civil Service*. URL: https://example.com/gov/sir-humphrey/importance-civil-service (visited on 23rd August 2018).]

Note that this example uses British and thus easily has the date order `dd. mm. yyyy`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129170/35864 if you want to stick to `english` or `american` or American spelling.

Comment: For more on getting the URL format to not use the American formatting see [Formatting dates “day month year” with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129170/35864), [DMY date and serial comma with Biblatex-chicago](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141355/35864)

Comment: `urldate=long` gave me "Apr." while I also needed `dateabbrev=false` to get "April"

Comment: @Florian Indeed the use of long or short month names (if names are used) is independent of the `...date` format used and is controlled by `dateabbrev` (and not as one might think by the generic `abbreviate` option).

Comment: I though I'd put this here for others who might also be puzzled by a `=long` date still being abbreviated...