# ISO Date format with Biblatex/Biber?

Tags: biblatex, biber, datetime, biblatex-chem

I'm using `biblatex`/`biber` with the `biblatex-chem` package to make a list of citations for group meeting. This works quite well, but I wanted to add a recent C&EN article to it, since it is quite relevant to my groups work. I can do this with the @online entry, but it uses the date in the form 03/03/2015 (dd/mm/yyyy) for the `urldate`. This is not the same as the article date format (MON. DD, YYYY). Regardless of is this is right for the format (it is for group meeting, not a publication), is there a way I can change both of these to ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD)? I've tried `\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}` with no success. [There is this answer, but it is rather intimidating, and I suspect would only change the date published, not date accessed.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167046/7880)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@online{Bonding,
  author = {Stu Borman},
  title = {Spying On Bond Making In Solution},
  year = 2015,
  month = 2,
  day = 19,
  url = {http://cen.acs.org/articles/93/i8/Spying-Bond-Making-Solution.html},
  urldate = {2015-03-03},
  addendum= {All about dicyanoaurate, has links to papers.}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-rsc,articletitle=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test.bib}

\begin{document}
Foo Bar Baz

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading = none]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Update #2 (`biblatex` >= 3.10)

Yet again new conventions in `biblatex` 3.10. Now `edtf` has been replaced by `iso`.

Updated MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@online{Bonding,
  author = {Stu Borman},
  title = {Spying On Bond Making In Solution},
  date = {2015-02-19},
  url = {http://cen.acs.org/articles/93/i8/Spying-Bond-Making-Solution.html},
  urldate = {2015-03-03},
  addendum= {All about dicyanoaurate, has links to papers.}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-rsc,articletitle=true,urldate=iso,date=iso,seconds=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
Foo Bar Baz

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading = none]
\end{document}
```

If all date formats have to be in ISO format (not only `date` and `urldate`) you can simply use `alldates=iso` instead of `urldate=iso` and `date=iso`.

---

### Update #1 (`biblatex` >= 3.5)

As of `biblatex` 3.5, `iso8601` is deprecated and `edtf` together with `seconds=true` should be used.

Using `day`, `month` and `year` as fields is also deprecated, so you should use the field

```
date = {2015-02-19},
```

in your `.bib` file instead of the three

```
year = 2015,
month = 02,
day = 19,
```

Updated MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@online{Bonding,
  author = {Stu Borman},
  title = {Spying On Bond Making In Solution},
  date = {2015-02-19},
  url = {http://cen.acs.org/articles/93/i8/Spying-Bond-Making-Solution.html},
  urldate = {2015-03-03},
  addendum= {All about dicyanoaurate, has links to papers.}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-rsc,articletitle=true,urldate=edtf,date=edtf,seconds=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
Foo Bar Baz

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading = none]
\end{document}
```

If all date formats have to be in ISO format (not only `date` and `urldate`) you can simply use `alldates=edtf` instead of `urldate=edtf` and `date=edtf`.

---

### Original answer

Add the options `urldate=iso8601` and `date=iso8601` when loading `biblatex` (and remember to add the leading zeroes in fields like `month` when needed).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@online{Bonding,
  author = {Stu Borman},
  title = {Spying On Bond Making In Solution},
  year = 2015,
  month = 02,
  day = 19,
  url = {http://cen.acs.org/articles/93/i8/Spying-Bond-Making-Solution.html},
  urldate = {2015-03-03},
  addendum= {All about dicyanoaurate, has links to papers.}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-rsc,articletitle=true,urldate=iso8601,date=iso8601]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
Foo Bar Baz

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading = none]
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: Using `\addbibresource` instead of `\bibliography` is recommended with `biblatex`.

---

If all date formats have to be in ISO format (not only `date` and `urldate`) you can simply use `alldates=iso8601` instead of `urldate=iso8601` and `date=iso8601`.

Comment: When I compile your example as-is and run `biber <file>` and recompile, I still get a single-digit value for month.

Comment: @Werner Add a leading zero in the `month` field.

Comment: Thanks. I had both in there with addbibresource commented out, I've switched it.

Comment: With version 3.5 the option `iso8601` is deprecated, use `edtf` instead.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, I've updated the answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update your answer. Indeed `day` is not only deprecated, even in some newer pre-2.5 Biber versions it was outright ignored.