# German date format with Biblatex/Biber?

Tags: biblatex, biber, date

[ISO Date format with Biblatex/Biber?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231208/iso-date-format-with-biblatex-biber#231215) answers the same question for the ISO date format, but I can't find information on how to use the German format (dd.mm.yyyy). [The documentation](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#page=51) is of no help, as only `year, short, long, terse, comp, ymd` and `edtf` are covered and there is no information on how to change the separator from `/` to `.`. I am using `american` in `babel` and neither `isodate` nor `datetime` had an effect on the bibliography.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want to change your whole bibliography or just some entries?

Comment: Could you prepare an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and if you use American in your main document do you want to change all dates or only the dates of some entries?

Comment: Datetime is obselete. It was replaced by datetime2. Have you tried if it works with that one?

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf `isodate`, `datetime` and `datetime2` are meant for other purpose. `biblatex` has control over the entries.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf I doubt `datetime2` has any bearing on the date in `biblatex`'s bibliography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date format depends on your language settings. This can be shown by the following example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[american,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\section{ngerman}
\begin{refsection}

\cite{ctan}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\selectlanguage{american}
\section{american}

\begin{refsection}
\cite{ctan}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

In your case you can use the default german definition of `\mkbibdatelong`/`\mkbibdateshort` to get your result:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[american,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{%
 %from german.lbx
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}\adddot
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\thinspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}
     {}
     {\iffieldundef{#3}{/}{\adddot\thinspace}}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\section{ngerman}
\begin{refsection}

\cite{ctan}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\selectlanguage{american}
\section{american}

\begin{refsection}
\cite{ctan}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]