# Australian date formatting with Biblatex and APA style?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, datetime

In my references I'd like my dates to be written as "day month year". I've been able to achieve this following the top answer here [Formatting dates “day month year” with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129170/formatting-dates-day-month-year-with-biblatex). However, as soon as I try to use that MWE with style=apa, I get the error "Undefined control sequence. \end" at the \printbibliography command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[australian,american]{babel}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{Book,
  title = {This is a Title},
  author = {Author, Some},
  location = {The City},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = 2005,
  month = feb,
  day = 14,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\today

Citing \cite{Book}.

\begin{otherlanguage}{australian}
\printbibliography
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For `biblatex-apa` to function one always needs the line `\DeclareLanguageMapping{<language>}{<language>-apa}`, but this is not available for `australian` (`australian-apa.lbx` does not exist). I think it might be easier to solve your problem in a different way. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'd just like the dates in my bibliography to be formatted as "10th of April, 2015", rather than "April 10, 2015".

Comment: You see, I'm asking because when I run your example with `american` only (and the necessary `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}`) I get "(2005, February 14)" in the output.

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant for the urldate parameter, i.e. the retrieval date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following redefinition in your preamble ought to be enough

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalongmdy#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}}
```

but since the current version of `biblatex-apa` used `\DefineBibliographyExtras` instead of `\DeclareBibliographyExtras` in its `.lbx` files that does not quite work. This bug [has already been resolved in the github repository](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/12), it has not made it to CTAN yet, though.

---

As a temporary work-around I suggest you create a new file called `american-bpb.lbx` and fill it with

```
\ProvidesFile{american-bpb.lbx}[2015/10/10\space v6.7\space APA biblatex localisation - modified]
\InheritBibliographyExtras{american-apa}

\DeclareBibliographyStrings{inherit = {american-apa}}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalongmdy#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}}

\endinput
```

In your document then use `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-bpb}` (instead of the normally required `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}`)

In the MWE we create the `american-bpb.lbx` via `filecontents`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{american-bpb.lbx}
\ProvidesFile{american-bpb.lbx}[2015/10/10\space v6.7\space APA biblatex localisation - modified]
\InheritBibliographyExtras{american-apa}

\DeclareBibliographyStrings{inherit = {american-apa}}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalongmdy#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-bpb}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{online,
  title = {Something on the Internet},
  author = {Anne Uthor},
  date = {2015-04-08},  
  url = {http://www.example.com},
  urldate = {2015-08-04},  
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]