# Mendeley problem displaying URL visiting date with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, urls

I'm using Mendeley to create a .bib file for my LaTeX file (I'm using BibLaTeX).
In Mendeley I define the field "Date Accessed" for a Web Page as, for example, 18 Sep 2015, so it automatically becomes 2015-09-18.
When I export to .bib, it shows urldate = {2015-09-18}.
However, when compiled, the bibliography shows "visited on 09/18/2015" (18 is a month that doesn't exist!!).

Strangely, there are other entries that are correct, but I set them exactly the same way, so I'm very confused. In this case, the .bib file shows the urldate in the format {yyyy-dd-mm}, but the output is how I want it (dd-mm-yyyy).

I also tried to force writing in Mendeley 2015-18-09, so that it is the format that BibLaTeX wants, but in that case I get an error saying that the date format is wrong.

Below, you can find an example that shows the correct date (4th Sep 2015) and one that shows the wrong date (18th Sep 2015). Both of them have been input in Mendeley exactly the same way.

```
@misc{Latitude,
author = {Wikipedia},
file = {:Users/nuri/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/2e0d0e2cfa61da92bdfb0de9a0276aef68d1ef5b.html:html},
month = sep,
title = {{Latitude}},
url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#Geocentric_latitude},
urldate = {2015-04-09},
year = {2015}
}
@misc{LatLonAlt,
author = {{H. Dana}, Peter},
file = {:Users/nuri/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/d44961957a5998c59a16ca94005b2ac1a1d715ea.html:html},
institution = {Department of Geography, University of Texas},
month = dec,
title = {{Coordinate Systems Overview}},
url = {http://www.colorado.edu/geography/gcraft/notes/coordsys/coordsys.html},
urldate = {2015-09-18},
year = {1999}
}
```

[image: Working example: 4th September 2015]

[image: Non-working example: it should be 18th September 2015]

I know this question is more related to Mendeley, but I just cannot find the answer anywhere. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What option did you give to `babel`? Can we see a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: This is quite unrelated to Mendeley, but it hinders your work. Get it into `biblatex` mode somehow. `@misc` should not be used for online resources, `@online` is available. Do you really think that *Wikipedia* is a citeable author? Wikipedia is the name of the project, *who* provided the information you are citing is probably unknown (a faceless crowd of users). Be careful here.

Comment: Maybe [Formatting dates “day month year” with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129170/35864) can help.

Comment: Note that your input `urldate = {2015-04-09}`, translates to 9. April 2015 and not 4. September 2015, since the input format for `date` fields in `biblatex` is always `YYYY-MM-DD`. As such the output is consistent with the other one, you get a MM/DD/YYYY format in both cases, which makes me think you use American language settings. Switch to Australian, British or change the date format. We can only help you with that if we get to see a full MWE though.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I didn't use `@misc` on purpose, it is generated automatically when using "Web Page" on Mendeley.
I know that Wikipedia is not the author, this is not my final version and it is within my list of things to do to fix this kind of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I solved the problem by adding the British babel package as suggested, and deleting and adding again some of the entries in Mendeley that had problems with the date no matter how many times I tried to change it.

```
\documentclass[11 pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your contributions.

Comment: Note that instead of saying `citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee` simply `style=ieee` is shorter and does the same.

Comment: I just noted that because sometimes you see something far more baffling things along the lines of `style=alphabetic, citestyle=authortitle, bibstyle=authoryear-icomp` which is terribly confusing and confused.

Answer (score 1):

The input format for all `date` fields in `biblatex` is always `yyyy-mm-dd` (with leading zeroes).

So your two `urldate`s are 9 April 2015 for `Latitude` and 18 September 2015 for `LatLonAlt`.

You get an output of MM/DD/YYYY, which is `biblatex`'s default for the American locale; the `american` localisation is also loaded if you don't specify a language or use `english`.

To change the date format you can switch language with `babel` to `british` or `australian` if you happen to use those dialects.

If you want to stick to American rules and just change the date format, go with

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
```

to load the British format for short dates.

If you also want to have the British long date format, you also need

```
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
```

in the `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}


\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Latitude,
  author    = {Wikipedia},
  title     = {Latitude},
  url       = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude},
  urldate   = {2015-04-09},
  date      = {2015-09},
}
@online{LatLonAlt,
  author      = {Dana, Peter H.},
  institution = {Department of Geography, University of Texas},
  title       = {Coordinate Systems Overview},
  url         = {http://www.colorado.edu/geography/gcraft/notes/coordsys/coordsys.html},
  urldate     = {2015-09-18},
  date        = {1999-12-15},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Peter H. Dana. Coordinate Systems Overview. Dec. 15, 1999. url: http://www.colorado.edu/geography/gcraft/notes/coordsys/coordsys.html (visited on 18/09/2015).//Wikipedia. Latitude. Sept. 2015. url: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude (visited on 09/04/2015).]