# Bibtex with url (with %-sign) in note-field wont compile

Tags: biblatex, urls

I have the following reference and the URL is causing the document to fail to compile. Tried everything I could think of. How to get this to work?

```
@misc{prodromou2010ostatus,
title={{OStatus 1.0}},
author={E. Prodromou and B. Vibber and J. Walker and Z. Copley},
note={\url{http://ostatus.github.io/spec/OStatus%201.0%20Draft%202.html} Accessed: 23.6.2017},
year={2010}
}
```

Comment: Could you consider using `biblatex`?

Comment: \usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,maxbibnames=20,firstinits=true,sorting=none]{biblatex} no option to change that

Comment: Please consider providing a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). If you are really using `biblatex` you should not be using `note`, but rather the dedicated `url` and `urldate` fields. Any reason why you can't change the backend? (Biber is preferred over the legacy backend BibTeX by `biblatex`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `biblatex` you should not use the `note` field to give the URL and date of access of a webpage. Instead use the dedicated fields `url` and `urldate`. `url` can deal with all kinds of characters that are special for TeX, as it is interpreted in verbatim mode.

```
@online{prodromou2010ostatus,
  title   = {OStatus 1.0},
  author  = {Evan Prodromou and Brion Vibber and James Walker and Zach Copley},
  date    = {2010-08-30},
  url     = {http://ostatus.github.io/spec/OStatus%201.0%20Draft%202.html},
  urldate = {2017-06-23},
}
```

The problem in your example indeed arose due to the `%`. In the `.bbl` many fields (amongst them `note`) are saved in the format

```
\field{<fieldname>}{<fieldcontent>}
```

If `<fieldcontent>` contains a `%` character, that `%` is interpreted as start of a comment and everything after it is ignored. That means in particular that the curly braces don't close, grouping is messed up and everything goes pear shaped. So in general one should avoid `%` and other special characters in fields, unless the fields are verbatim fields such as `url`.
This also holds for fields that you do not see in the output, but are still recognised by `biblatex` - one of these is `abstract` which is often pre-filled if you download a `.bib` file from the internet and may contain all sorts of characters that cause trouble if the exporting tool was not careful. Even if your style does not print the field, problematic characters there can still mess things up.

Note that even though Biber is recommended over BibTeX nowadays, in this instance switching to Biber does not help. You should still consider using Biber, though. <sub>In case of problems with the `abstract` field BibTeX is a bit more forgiving than Biber in some situations. But that should not be an argument to prefer BibTeX.</sub>

Comment: thanks for the explanation. yet, is there any way to configure the urldate to be in "normal" instead of US format - i.e. 23.6.2017 instead of 6/23/2017?

Comment: @Xenonite See [Mendeley problem displaying URL visiting date with Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269304/35864) [Formatting dates “day month year” with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129170/35864), [DMY date and serial comma with Biblatex-chicago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141355/35864). If that does not work out to your satisfaction, please ask a new question and include a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), the answer to this question depends on your document setup.