# biblatex urldate order: change from m/d/y to d/m/y

Tags: biblatex, date, url

url's in my bibliography are printed like m/d/y but I want it to be printed as d/m/y. How can I force biblatex to do that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage[backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,urldate=short,sortlocale=danish,firstinits=true,style=authoryear-icomp,dashed=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=true,]{biblatex}
```

Comment: That's not an MWE, it is not complete and so can't be used for a test. Complete it with e.g. entries from `biblatex-examples.bib`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for your comment. I believe that what you are referring to is an MWEB (including bibliographic examples), which you are right that I did not provide. Would that be an advantage here?

Comment: Well I almost always test my solutions, and if there is not document to test them in the question either I have  to spent *my* time to build one or I have to ignore the question.

Comment: @jbahn: Does this answer help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269653/134144 ?

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex` can't automatically detect the language variant with `polyglossia`.

You need to add

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{UKenglish}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: Adding this to the preamble still yields the url date in mm/dd/yyyy format while OP requested dd/mm/yyyy format. According to this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129209/134144), the australian language might be a solution although it has some drawbacks. So maybe the solution presented in this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269653/134144) might be better.

Comment: @leandriis, you're right! I would have thought that `british` should be the same as `australian`. I'll change my answer. There should be no side effects in using `australian` rather than `british`.

Comment: @leandriis, actually I think there is a bug somewhere. `british` gives mm/dd/yyyy, but `UKenglish` gives `dd/mm/yyyy`. Given that `UKenglish` simply inherits from `british` without changing anything, they should be identical.

Comment: When I add <\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{UKenglish}> to my preamble I get this error: Undefined control sequence. \DeclareLanguageMapping

Comment: @DavidPurton That's indeed interesting and seems to be reproducible using different versions of `biblatex`.

Comment: Does i matter where in preamble I add <\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{UKenglish}>?

Comment: BTW, I also have <\setotherlanguage{danish}> after <\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english> in my preamble. Could that interfere?

Comment: `\DeclareLanguageMapping` must come after `\usepackage{biblatex}`

Comment: I submitted a bug report to `biblatex`: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/677

Comment: polyglossia variants doesn't work well in biblatex as a sensible interface is missing. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324849/how-do-we-get-polyglossia-language-variants-to-work-with-biblatex-bibliographies, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/460 and https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/154. I would avoid polyglossia here if possible and use babel instead. \DeclareLanguageMapping is not meant for variants (see the biblatex docu).