# Biblatex reference list not translated to Bahasa Indonesia

Tags: biblatex, babel, polyglossia

Currently, I am following a tutorial on overleaf [about bibliography generation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX). I tried to use Bahasa Indonesia language in my next document, so I load `polyglossia` package and set the main language to `bahasai` for Bahasa Indonesia. But some words in the reference list is not translated into bahasa Indonesia at all. How should I fix this problem? (I tried to use `babel`, it didn't work either).

```
    
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{bahasai}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}

\usepackage{sourceserifpro}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ext-authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear-comp,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}

%\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}

  
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\adddot\space}

\title{Bibliography management: \texttt{biblatex} package}
\author{Muhamad Abdul Rosid}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Bagian 1}
Using \texttt{biblatex} you can display bibliography divided into sections, depending on citation type. \textcite{einstein} published a book call DUMMY text. It's just dummy, no need to worry about this.

Let's cite! \citeauthor{einstein}'s journal paper \parencite[lihat][]{einstein} and the Dirac's book \parencite{dirac} are physics related items.
\section{Bagian 2}
Next, \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \parencite{latexcompanion}, the Donald Knuth's website \parencite{knuthwebsite}, \textit{The Comprehensive Tex Archive Network} (CTAN) \parencite{ctan} are \LaTeX\ related items; but the others Donald Knuth's items \parencite{knuth-fa,knuth-acp} are dedicated to programming.

\medskip

\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={Daftar Pustaka}
]

%\printbibliography[type=article,title={Articles only}]
%\printbibliography[type=book,title={Books only}]
%
%\printbibliography[keyword={physics},title={Physics-related only}]
%\printbibliography[keyword={latex},title={\LaTeX-related only}]
\end{document}
```

The `sample.bib` is as follows,

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
  keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  isbn={9780198520115},
  series={International series of monographs on physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
  keywords = {physics}
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens dan Frank Mittelbach dan Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts",
    keywords  = "latex"
}
 
@online{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = "1973",
   chapter = "1.2",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@book{knuth-acp,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   title = "The Art of Computer Programming",
   series = "Four volumes",
   year = "1968",
   note = "Seven volumes planned",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@article{ctan,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351",
    keywords  = "latex"
}
```

The output is like this.
[image]
Look at the reference list. the word `in`, `and`, `pages`, and `chapter` are not translated to Bahasa Indonesia.

Comment: Basically `biblatex` does not speak Bahasa Indonesia, it simply does not have the localisation files for that language. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864 explains the general procedure to write the necessary language definitions, but if you would like to contribute the Bahasa Indonesia localisation for `biblatex` you can also drop by https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues.

Comment: Just a comment. Currently the name in `babel` is `indonesian` (although `bahasai` still works).

Answer (score 1):

I did steps on [What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200932/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-configure-biblatex-for-use-with-an-unsupport) and [Formatting dates “day month year” with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129170/formatting-dates-day-month-year-with-biblatex) (but successful only with @Cerran answer).

Here are the files; shared for public: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16X0YVHXU1GgU4-ycB_eR5tMAy-5n7gdr?usp=sharing

Note: they are my personal edit, not something formal / legal (i.e., not approved by govt. body nor submitted for approval).

Comment: Can you help me how to use .lbx files in MacOS? I use MacTeX.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/261274)