# Reference date (Year, Month Day)

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I've been trying to follow the APA style for article date (Year, Month Day), but after reading the documentation of `biblatex`, the closest I've come is (Month, Day Year). Does anyone know a solution to this?

From this:

[image: Here is what I have now]

To this:

[image: Here is what I would like]

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% ----- Sources -----
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=nyt, datelabel=comp, dateabbrev= false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Grebe2017}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And my References.bib:

```
\@online{Grebe2017,
title = {Beyond the Hype: The Real Champions of Building the Digital Future},
date = {2017-07-10},
author = {Michael Grebe and Michael Rüßmann and Michael Leyh},
institution = {BCG},
url = {https://www.bcg.com/publications/2017/technology-digital-beyond-hype}}
```

Comment: Here you have different solutions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129170/formatting-dates-day-month-year-with-biblatex

Answer (score 2):

With specialised custom styles like `biblatex-apa` it is usually best not to use that many additional `biblatex` options that influence the output.

In this case the culprit is `datelabel=comp,` as it switches from the APA-style date to `biblatex`'s standard `comp` format. Remove the option. Likewise you should remove `dateabbrev=false`.

The option `sorting=nyt,` should also be removed, since `biblatex-apa` comes with its own sorting scheme that sorts things according to APA specifications.

So you should change the `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=nyt, datelabel=comp, dateabbrev= false]{biblatex}` to

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
```

Then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{Grebe2017,
  title       = {Beyond the Hype: The Real Champions of Building the Digital Future},
  date        = {2017-07-10},
  author      = {Michael Grebe and Michael Rüßmann and Michael Leyh},
  institution = {BCG},
  url         = {https://www.bcg.com/publications/2017/technology-digital-beyond-hype},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Grebe2017}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: Grebe, M., Rüßmann, M., & Leyh, M. (2017, July 10). Beyond the hype: The real champions of building the digital future. https://www.bcg.com/publications/2017/technology-digital-beyond-hype]

as desired.