# How change the date format of url field of biblatex package?

Tags: biblatex, urls, bibliographystyle, date, format

I need to print, for instance, `15 October 2022` and not the `15th October 2022`. I found a similar question [old_solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129170/formatting-dates-day-month-year-with-biblatex) where it is reported to use the australian language since it formats the dates according my wish. I would want to avoid using another language.
Here my settings for language and `biblatex`:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=numeric-comp, % authoryear
    bibstyle=numeric-comp, % authoryear,
    doi=false,url=true,isbn=false,
%   sorting=nyt,% none
    hyperref=true,
%   %style=apa,
    block=ragged,      
    urldate=long,      
    dateabbrev=false,  
    natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant language-dependent macro is `\mkbibdatelong` [whose definition in `british.lbx` you'll find in ll. 20-31](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/868b79fecb7998742eae53d2f81bb637453ceaf7/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/british.lbx#L20-L31). We want to get rid of the ordinal day number, so we go with

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric-comp,
  doi=false,url=true,isbn=false,
  block=ragged,      
  urldate=long,      
  dateabbrev=false,  
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,ctan}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: CTAN. The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network. 2006. url: http://www.ctan.org (visited on 1 October 2006).]