# customize urldate on bibtex

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the following for my bibtex.

`\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=mla,sorting=nty]{biblatex} % bibliography`

This will display the following for my Works Cited section.
[image]

The following is a code for bibtex.

```
@article{alberts,
author = {Alberts, Bruce},
title = {Cell theory},
journal = {Britannica},
url = "britannica.com/science/cell-theory",
urldate = {2023-06-28},
date = {2023-06-28}
}
```

I want to make my bibliography look like

> Alberts, Bruce. "Cell theory". *Britannica*, 28 June 2023. britannica.com/science/cell-theory. Accessed 28 June 2023.

How can I format `urldate` to 'day month year' style?

This is my package and preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
    @article{alberts,
    author = {Alberts, Bruce},
    title = {Cell theory},
    journal = {Britannica},
    url = "britannica.com/science/cell-theory",
    urldate = {2023-06-28},
    date = {2023-06-28}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % International characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Font encoding for international characters
% \usepackage{fouriernc} % Use the New Century Schoolbook font
\usepackage{lmodern} % Use Latin Modern font
% \usepackage{libertine} % Use LLibertine font
% \usepackage{libertinust1math}% Use LLibertine math font
\usepackage{geometry} % Setting page geometry (margins)
\usepackage{blindtext} % Lorem ipsum
\usepackage{textcomp} % For the trademark symbol
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables for horizontal lines
\usepackage{microtype} % A few refinements to typography that are hardly noticeable
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} %Strikethrough text
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{cases}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
}

%Itemize
\usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{setspace}

%Fonts
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

% Package must come last
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref} % Hyperrefs for bookmarks
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}
\usepackage{bookmark} % Adds metadata to PDF for bookmarking
% Package settings & macros

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents} % Contents heading

\urldef{\usePercentage}\url{%} % Using the percent symbol in documents: \usePercentage

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=mla,sorting=nty]{biblatex} % bibliography

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\def\signed #1{{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em
  \hbox{}\nobreak\hfil(#1)%
  \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \endgraf}}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newenvironment{aquote}[1]
  {\savebox\mybox{#1}\begin{quote}}
  {\signed{\usebox\mybox}\end{quote}}

\geometry{margin=1in}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
  
\begin{document}
 
Parencite \parencite{alberts}.
 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hsve you considered changing the three fields `day = {28}`, `month = {June},` `year = {2023},` to a *single* field, viz., `date = 2023-06-28`?

Comment: Thanks! That solved my first issue!!

Comment: The format of date fields in the output depends on your language settings. Please show us a small example document (beginning with `\documentclass`, along with a preamble loading just the packages relevant for language and bibliography setup and a small `\begin{document}...\end{document}` body with some dummy contents for citations) that reproduces the output you get at the moment. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I added my source codes!

Comment: By default `biblatex`'s `english` localisation uses the American date format (mm/dd/yyyy). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129170/35864 (read all answers before you decide on a solution) for a way to get a different date format.

Comment: You may want to clean up your preamble. You load a lot of packages. Do you know what each of them does? Do you need all of them? In any case you should make sure to load each package only once. Loading packages several times may confuse you and can lead to the dreaded "option clash" errors.

Comment: I deleted unnecessary packages for this essay.